# I am using cardview with gridview and in design panel my coding output is ok but when i run it on any android phone it is not working

Tags: android, android-layout, android-applicationinfo

**This is my XML code for gridview with cardview and it is appearing alright in the design panel but when I run it on my phone that has android oreo go edition it is showing like this**

[This is an image of how it appears on my phone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rsmk3.jpg)

[This is an image of how it appears in my android studio's design panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/byr9u.jpg)

```
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" 
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:weightSum="10" 
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
        
        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light">
        
            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:id="@+id/first"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:text="Android Based Attendance Management System"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.125">
        
            </androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView>
        
            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:id="@+id/second"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Integrated With"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.50">
        
            </androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView>
        
            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:id="@+id/third"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="QR"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.50"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.80">
            </androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView>
        
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
        
        <androidx.gridlayout.widget.GridLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="8"
            android:padding="14dp"
            app:alignmentMode="alignMargins"
            app:columnOrderPreserved="true"
            app:rowCount="2"
            app:columnCount="2">
        
            <!-- Row1 starts !-->
        
            <!-- Column1 starts !-->
        
            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
                app:cardElevation="8dp"
                app:layout_columnWeight="1"
                app:layout_rowWeight="1">
        
                <androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_margin="16dp">
        
                    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:src="@drawable/admin_home_page_logo">
        
                    </androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView>
        
                    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        
                    </androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView>
        
                </androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>
        
            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
        
            <!-- Column1 ends !-->
        
        
            <!-- Column2 starts !-->
        
            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
                app:cardElevation="8dp"
                app:layout_columnWeight="1"
                app:layout_rowWeight="1">
        
        
                <androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_margin="16dp">
        
                    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:src="@drawable/teacher_logo">
        
                    </androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView>
        
                    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        
                    </androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView>
        
                </androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>
        
        
            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
        
            <!-- Column2 ends !-->
        
            <!-- Row1 ends !-->
        
        
        
            <!-- Row2 starts !-->
        
            <!-- Column1 starts !-->
        
            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
                app:cardElevation="8dp"
                app:layout_columnWeight="1"
                app:layout_rowWeight="1">
        
        
                <androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_margin="16dp">
        
                    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:src="@drawable/students_logo">
        
                    </androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView>
        
                    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        
                    </androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView>
        
                </androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>
        
        
            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
        
            <!-- Column1 ends !-->
        
        
            <!-- Column2 starts !-->
        
            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
                app:cardElevation="8dp"
                app:layout_columnWeight="1"
                app:layout_rowWeight="1">
        
        
                <androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_margin="16dp">
        
                    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:src="@drawable/parents_logo2">
        
                    </androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView>
        
                    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        
                    </androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView>
        
                </androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>
        
        
            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
        
            <!-- Column2 ends !-->
        
            <!-- Row2 ends !-->
        
        </androidx.gridlayout.widget.GridLayout>
        </androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>
```

### And this is how my Gradle build is:

```
    
plugins { id 'com.android.application' }
    
    android { compileSdkVersion 30 buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"
    
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.androidbasedattendancemanagementsystemusingqr"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}
    
    dependencies {
    
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.gridlayout:gridlayout:1.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
    }
```

Comment: Please don't tag questions with the android-studio tag just because you use it: the Android Studio tag should **only** be used when you have questions about the IDE itself, and not any code you write (or want to write) in it. See [when is it appropriate to remove an IDE tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/315196/6296561), [How do I avoid misusing tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/354427/6296561), and [the tagging guide](/help/tagging). Use [android] or other relevant tags instead.

Answer (score 0):

The picture on your phone is showing a `Toolbar`. If you do not want it to have a `Toolbar` then make sure you are using `.NoActionBar` in your Theme.